# Does the Fire to Snake spell only work on an elongated fire?

Tags: harry-potter

Does the Fire to Snake spell only work on an elongated fire?

On the two instances we saw them being used, the fire's shape was longer than it was wide. In Dumbledore's duel with Voldemort, Dumbledore ensnared Voldemort with a fiery rope, and most or all ropes are longer than they are wide. In McGonagall's duel with Snape, the fire from the torch fell from its bracket and created a lasso as it reacted with the air/wind, thus elongating it and making it longer than it is wide.

Does the Fire to Snake spell only work on an elongated fire? Or can it work on any shape of fire?

Comment: It’s possible it’s not a ‘Spell’ in its own right; more likely perhaps that it’s an overarching spell and this happens to be one use of it.

Comment: It could be that they are reminded in battle of analogous uses of things. A suit of armour as a body shield, charging desks for instance. A Slytherin would be likely to see long snake-like objects and transfigure accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that said spell is a Transfiguration spell and applying the general rules of Transfiguration that we see in the books, it would work in any fire source, but would be easier to perform in a fire that has more similarities to a snake (for example, it is elongated).